# Xbee series 2 Intermittent Packets

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I have two xbee series 2 (ZigBee) radios, and I am having some trouble getting them to communicate properly.  One xbee is running the ZigBee Router AT firmware version 22A0, and one xbee is running the ZigBee Coordinator API firmware version 21A0.  The ZigBee Router is also set to sample DIO4 (digital pin 4) every 100 ms.  The ZigBee Coordinator is connected to my computer with a USB explorer, and I am using the "new" XCTU program to read packets from serial.  The ZigBee Router is simply being powered by a 3.3V connection.  I can see some ZigBee IO Data Sample RX Indicator packets come through but they are intermittent and not consistent. Also, I have trouble discovering the remote  node through XTCU.  Below I have posted the saved profiles for both the router and the coordinator so you can see all of the settings and firmware.  Is this a configuration issue or is one of the radios bad?

Zigbee Coordinator API profile:

```
<data>
  <profile>
    <description_file>XB24-ZB_21A0.xml</description_file>
    <settings>
      <setting command="ID">0</setting>
      <setting command="SC">FFFF</setting>
      <setting command="SD">3</setting>
      <setting command="ZS">0</setting>
      <setting command="NJ">FF</setting>
      <setting command="DH">0</setting>
      <setting command="DL">FFFF</setting>
      <setting command="NI">0x20</setting>
      <setting command="NH">30</setting>
      <setting command="BH">0</setting>
      <setting command="AR">FF</setting>
      <setting command="DD">30000</setting>
      <setting command="NT">3C</setting>
      <setting command="NO">3</setting>
      <setting command="CR">3</setting>
      <setting command="PL">4</setting>
      <setting command="PM">1</setting>
      <setting command="EE">0</setting>
      <setting command="EO">0</setting>
      <setting command="KY"></setting>
      <setting command="NK"></setting>
      <setting command="BD">3</setting>
      <setting command="NB">0</setting>
      <setting command="SB">0</setting>
      <setting command="D7">1</setting>
      <setting command="D6">0</setting>
      <setting command="AP">1</setting>
      <setting command="AO">0</setting>
      <setting command="SP">20</setting>
      <setting command="SN">1</setting>
      <setting command="D0">1</setting>
      <setting command="D1">0</setting>
      <setting command="D2">0</setting>
      <setting command="D3">0</setting>
      <setting command="D4">0</setting>
      <setting command="D5">1</setting>
      <setting command="P0">1</setting>
      <setting command="P1">0</setting>
      <setting command="P2">0</setting>
      <setting command="PR">1FFF</setting>
      <setting command="LT">0</setting>
      <setting command="RP">28</setting>
      <setting command="IR">0</setting>
      <setting command="IC">0</setting>
      <setting command="V+">0</setting>
    </settings>
  </profile>
</data>
```

Zigbee Router AT profile:

```
<data>
  <profile>
    <description_file>XB24-ZB_22A0.xml</description_file>
    <settings>
      <setting command="ID">0</setting>
      <setting command="SC">FFFF</setting>
      <setting command="SD">3</setting>
      <setting command="ZS">0</setting>
      <setting command="NJ">FF</setting>
      <setting command="NW">0</setting>
      <setting command="JV">1</setting>
      <setting command="JN">0</setting>
      <setting command="DH">0</setting>
      <setting command="DL">FFFF</setting>
      <setting command="NI">0x20</setting>
      <setting command="NH">1E</setting>
      <setting command="BH">0</setting>
      <setting command="AR">FF</setting>
      <setting command="DD">30000</setting>
      <setting command="NT">3C</setting>
      <setting command="NO">3</setting>
      <setting command="CR">3</setting>
      <setting command="SE">E8</setting>
      <setting command="DE">E8</setting>
      <setting command="CI">11</setting>
      <setting command="PL">4</setting>
      <setting command="PM">1</setting>
      <setting command="EE">0</setting>
      <setting command="EO">0</setting>
      <setting command="KY"></setting>
      <setting command="BD">3</setting>
      <setting command="NB">0</setting>
      <setting command="SB">0</setting>
      <setting command="RO">3</setting>
      <setting command="D7">1</setting>
      <setting command="D6">0</setting>
      <setting command="CT">64</setting>
      <setting command="GT">3E8</setting>
      <setting command="CC">2B</setting>
      <setting command="SM">0</setting>
      <setting command="SN">1</setting>
      <setting command="SO">0</setting>
      <setting command="SP">20</setting>
      <setting command="ST">1388</setting>
      <setting command="D0">1</setting>
      <setting command="D1">0</setting>
      <setting command="D2">0</setting>
      <setting command="D3">0</setting>
      <setting command="D4">3</setting>
      <setting command="D5">1</setting>
      <setting command="P0">1</setting>
      <setting command="P1">0</setting>
      <setting command="P2">0</setting>
      <setting command="PR">1FFF</setting>
      <setting command="LT">0</setting>
      <setting command="RP">28</setting>
      <setting command="IR">100</setting>
      <setting command="IC">0</setting>
      <setting command="V+">0</setting>
    </settings>
  </profile>
</data>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what “to communicate properly”, “not consistent” and “have trouble” mean? Is it communicating, but improperly? What made you conclude it is not working correctly?

Comment: I get a short burst of packets followed by silence and then eventually another short burst of packets.  The number of packets varies each time, sometimes it is 7 or 8 and sometimes it is only 1 or 2.  The time between bursts also seems to vary.  I assume that I should be receiving packets at a regular interval based on the 100 ms sample rate.